# Do I need to add the ppa before update a software via terminal?

Tags: 13.10, ppa, skype, vlc

Before updating a software which canonical does not support for updates (like vlc, Skype), do I need to add the relevant ppa to the system before run "apt-get install packagename" or "apt-get --only upgrade install packagename" ?
(I'm using ubuntu 13.10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly the answer is

#### No.

The Ubuntu repositories contain both VLC and Skype, but you might be able to get newer versions from a PPA.

One way to tell if the package you want is in your current repos (including any PPAs you've already added) is:

```
apt-cache search <packages-name>
```

Or you can open the software center and search. PPAs are only for software that isn't already in the repos.

Answer (score 0):

For software are not available in Ubuntu repository **Yes**, You have to add APP before updating list, then try to install software related to APP.